# Looking for a way to convert image folder to a WEBM video slideshow using FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a slideshow video in WEBM format using `ffmpeg`.

I could create a video slideshow in MP4 format using the below command:

```
exec('ffmpeg -r 10 -s 1080x1620 -i images/img%03d.jpeg -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 output.mp4', $output, $exit_status);
```

But when I am trying to create a video slideshow in WEBM format, it's not returning anything:

```
exec('ffmpeg -framerate 25 -f image2 -i images/img%03d.png -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p output.webm', $output, $exit_status);
```

Can someone please guide me on this. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Comment: Sorry for the same. I didnt know this. I am very new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of your command, and you can see the error like this,

```
[libvpx @ 000001e90e004980] v1.11.0
[libvpx @ 000001e90e004980] Transparency encoding with auto_alt_ref does not work
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

This error means you should set `auto-alt-ref` parameter.

Add this parameter, for example `-auto-alt-ref 0`, your command should works and generete the video.

```
-auto-alt-ref 0: This parameter disables automatic alternate reference frame generation. Setting it to 0 prevents FFmpeg from using alternate reference frames, which can sometimes cause issues with transparency encoding.
```